# Delay in syncing the DELTA changes from contentful in android

Tags: android, content-management-system, contentful

I am newbie to contentful and I have written an android application which uses content delivery API to fetch the content from my space.

I have used Vault and normal API (without vault) to fetch the content.

I observe that there is always a 3-5 seconds of delay in fetching the delta changes (new and update content).

My requirement is to give a real time data sync.

Is this an issue with my implementation or its an expected behaviour from contentful.

Sample code:
1. Using Vault

```
Vault.with(App.getInstance(), SampleSpace.class).requestSync(
            SyncConfig.builder()
                    .setClient(ClientProvider.get())
                    .setInvalidate(false)
                    .build());
List<SampleTable> appointments = Vault.with(App.getInstance(), SampleSpace.class)
            .fetch(SampleTable.class)
            .where(SampleTable$Fields.DATE+"=?", mDateToCheck)
            .all();
```

2. Normal API

   ```
   private final CDAClient client =   CDAClient.builder().setToken(CDA_TOKEN).setSpace(SPACE_ID).build();

   client.observe(CDAEntry.class).all()
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .subscribe(new Action1<CDAArray>() {
   @Override
   public void call(CDAArray entries) {
        //business logic here
     }});
   ```

Thanks for your time and help!!

Comment: AFAIK it is normal behaviour from contentful it will take some couple of seconds to fetch the data.

Comment: Thank you for your technical support.  I couldn't find those details in contentful official link. If my understanding is right, then I can't use contentful for enterprise/real time scenarios. Do you have any suggestion for using mobile CMS for real time scenario? Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a maintainer of the Java and Android SDKs in Contentful.

There could be some reasons for the slowdown:

**1) You are `syncing` a lot of data**

This would mean, that a lot of data, potentially even different pages have to be fetched from Contentful, parsed, serialised and put into the database in the Vault case.

In this case taking a look at fetching the entries by id and not using sync might be an idea. Sadly you would loose the niceness of Vault model classes and would need to implement the mapping from Contentful models to your custom models yourself.

**2) ClassLoader.getResources**

In your code snippet, you are recreating a `CDAClient` or `Vault` with every sync call. This has a [known issue](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.java/issues/119) on Android and we are currently working on fixing it.

For now, till an update is out, the recommendation is to try and see if storing `Vault` and/or the `CDAClient` in a field might be helpful for subsequent calls.

**3) The network is slow**

Sadly this would mean, there is nothing we can do from our side ... ;)

I hope this gives you some pointers, on a solution, please feel free to report back with any progress you encounter.

Comment: Thank you. Our data in the content space is very less. Syncing does't take much time for us, but the issue is with getting the delta changes in the response.
 Ex 1: I publish new data/changes in contentful portal. I use Vault's requestSync API to sync from my android application. The delta changes (newly added/updated content) doesn't come in the immediate sync response. I have to wait for 5 to 10 seconds and do a resync to receive the delta changes.

Comment: Ex 2: I add an entry to a content model from android app via CMAClient object. I do a requestSync() from android app. I didnt get the delta changes in the immediate sync response. I have to wait for 5 to 10 seconds.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately that is the way Contentful works. If you push something on the management side of things, you have a delay of several seconds, till it is appearing on the delivery side.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I find to this issue is to use Contentful Preview API.
So when some object is modified/deleted/created, the response speed will be the same. That being said, the user can get every update in one second or less in the app/web.

The problem is the app will be showing entries that are published or not (draft),so it depends on the project requierements.

In case the user needs to use this solution, he must use the **Content Preview API - access token** which is in APIs top panel section in Contentful. I hope it helps!